# 議論する場としてreading of 場

Tags: kanji, readings

In the phrase 議論する場として (from [this Wiki page](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%89%E9%83%A8%E4%BC%9A)) which is the correct reading of 場? じょう or ば?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[場{ば}](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%A0%B4_%28%E3%81%B0%29/#jn-172829)

> ある事が行われる所。「仕事の場」「場を外す」「その場に居合わせる」